# eclipse navigator display icon file as is

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have a folder which just contains 16x16 png icons in my rcp project.

I wonder is there a way or a hack, can make the package explorer display these icons files as is. that will make me feel convenient.

[image]
these icons is displayed as a normal document.

**when I try to install PDE-tool on indigo for rcp:**

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Jeeeyul's PDE-Tools 1.1.0.201211201045 (net.jeeeyul.pdetools.feature.feature.group 1.1.0.201211201045)
  Missing requirement: PDE-Tools 1.1.0.201211201045 (net.jeeeyul.pdetools 1.1.0.201211201045) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.ui.trace 0.0.0' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Jeeeyul's PDE-Tools 1.1.0.201211201045 (net.jeeeyul.pdetools.feature.feature.group 1.1.0.201211201045)
    To: net.jeeeyul.pdetools [1.1.0.201211201045]
```

**------------------------------------------------------------------------------- edit**
I just copyed the org.eclipse.ui.trace.jar from eclipse 4.2(juno) into eclipse 3.7(indigo) rcp, then installed PDE-Tools successfully. It seems work for me!

Comment: The installation dependency problem has been fixed in a newer version of PDE tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install the [PDE tools plugin](https://github.com/jeeeyul/pde-tools). It has an icon preview decorator, which [shows the content of the icons](https://github.com/jeeeyul/pde-tools#icon-preview) instead of the standard icon.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: It sounds cool! but I have problem when install it. see my question edit